# Is "main" a reserved word in PHP?

Tags: php, notepad++

I was prototyping a controller class in Notepad++ and I wanted to use `main` as a method name when I noticed that the word turned blue. Usually keywords in Notepad++ turn blue. So this made me think that I was not allowed to use it. But when I tried to write code using `main` and ran it, it worked fine and didn't give me any errors. Here is the test code I tried:

```
<?php

// testing method named "main"
class MyClass {
    public function main() {
        echo "foo";
    }
}
$ob = new MyClass();
$ob->main();

// testing function named "main"
function main() {
    echo 'bar';
}
main();
```

It just printed "foo" and "bar" as expected. I found [this page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.main.php) in the PHP docs and it said that "main" is used in the internal source code. It doesn't say that it is reserved and that you shouldn't use it. Even though it worked in my test, I'm afraid of potential gotchas in the future.

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about *this* one.

Comment: no http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php

Comment: @Dagon you've a plugin for that? or is it built-in?

Comment: You need not to be worried about that. It's just syntax highlighting provided for  `main`  in Notepad++. Maybe you should check the syntax highlighting language selected in the editor. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php

Comment: @Dagon Now how cool is that, thanks. I didn't know that. +1

Comment: @Dagon actually, I just pasted their code in my notepad++ and it did show "main" in blue, but when I changed it to "main1" it went black; thoughts? even `<?php

main;` went blue.

Comment: @Dagon I tested on both 6.9 and 7.2.2, same thing.

Comment: [nope](http://php.net/manual/en/function.main.php).

Comment: @Dagon Sorry, no can do but I can assure you it's blue in both 6.9 and 7.2.2

Comment: I think the question might be off-topic to a certain extent since it's somewhat related to software.

Comment: @Dagon under which version is that? and the 2nd one?

Comment: @Dagon maybe the older version didn't have syntax / function checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a reserved word, it should work just fine the way you wrote it. I tested on my machine to be sure as well (php 5.6 & php 7)

For reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php